# MySQL order by time on two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider I have the following two tables (rough sketches):

Table 1:

- t1Id (Int, Primary Key)
- time (Datetime)
- attribute1
- attribute2
- attribute3

Table 2:

- t2Id (Int, Primary Key)
- time (Datetime)
- attribute4
- attribute5

Suppose I want to select results from both tables and order them by `time`, is this doable? I myself was thinking it would be possible, if:

- You could create an union with all columns of both tables, but `time` being shared over the union.
- `NULL` values in places where this is no match. For example a row of Table 1 in this union would have `NULL` in t2Id, attribute4 and attribute5.
- An extra column indicating from which table the original rows (the ones without `NULL` values) originated from.

How would I design such a query in the most efficient way?

Comment: I would do it like you are mentioning: UNION with ORDER BY time. the extra column is up to you. If you want something to let you know from where it came from.

Comment: And what's wrong with `UNION` + `ORDER BY` ? If you want your result as one set, you should do exact that. As for `NULL`-s: clarify what's wrong with them: for union all your tables must have same count of columns

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT t1Id,time , attribute1,attribute2,attribute3 FROM table1 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t2Id ,time , attribute3,attribute4,"" FROM table2  
)AA
ORDER BY AA.time
```

Comment: that doesn't look very practical. You wouldn't know which ones are which. at least put a column after telling if they are from table1 or table2